# WP DB Sessions - simplest load balancer

Tags: wordpress, memcached, session-cookies

Many WP related articles claim that session hash is stored in WP database, and is checked against cookies saved. Is this true?

Asking this because, I've 2 servers running the exact same WP app with literally same configs, and on the same domain, using the same ( external ) database. If above is true( WP DB Sessions ), wouldn't that mean that whichever server I visit, I should be logged in automatically? Or do I actually need memcached for this kind of setup?